# Find number of Instances for few words in string while ignoring other few words using regex

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-group, regex-negation

Hi i am using regex in Matlab.

I need to find number of hits for few words while ignoring other few words using regex

what i have tried so far:

```
String = 'Sunday:Monday:Tuesday:Wednesday:Thursday:Friday:Saturday:Sun:Mon:Tue:Wed:,Thu:,Fri:,Sat:';
Output = regexp( String,'^(?!.*(,Sun:|,Sunday:)).*(Sun:|Sunday:)' )
```

The Output of above regexp comes as ***true***, But need it as 2 as it got ***hit 2 times*** for ***Sun:*** and ***Sunday:***.

In next Scenario:

```
String = 'Sunday:Monday:Tuesday:Wednesday:Thursday:Friday:Saturday:Sun:Mon:Tue:Wed:,Thu:,Fri:,Sat:';
Output = regexp( String,'^(?!.*(,Fri:|,Friday:)).*(Fri:|Friday:)' )
```

The Output of above regexp comes as ***false***, But need it as 1 as it*** got hit 1 time*** for ***Friday:***.

I also tried:

```
regexp( String,'^(?!.*(,Sun:|,Sunday:)).*(Sun:|Sunday:)' ,'match')
```

But its giving Output as whole string.
I am confused how to get number of hits while ignoring other words, Help would be appreciated regexp work in Matlab same as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```matlab
(?<!,)Fri(?:day)?:
```

It matches

- `(?<!,)` - a location not immediately preceded with `,`
- `Fri` - `Fri`
- `(?:day)?` - an optional `day` string
- `:` - a colon.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ISjiNG/1).

If you allow some redundancy, you may build the pattern like this:

```js
(?<!,)(Fri:|Sunday:)
```

It will match `Fri:` or `Sunday:` not immediately preceded with a comma.

Comment: Actually i dont want to keep dependancy on day. can it be made like find these words and ignore these words or ignore if it have "," preceding Let me reframe my question Output = regexp( String,'^(?!.*(,Fri:|,Sunday:)).*(Fri:|Sunday:)' )  Now answer should be 2 as it got hit for both

Comment: @Chetan.B `(?<!,)(Fri:|Sunday:)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to use regexp, something like this will be easier to maintain:

```
Output = sum(ismember(strsplit(String,':'),{'Sunday','Sun'}))
```